# nvd3 library, How to customize line chart

Tags: css, svg, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 to draw some stats in my app.
I would like to increase the thickness of the line in my charts. How can it be possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Search for the class, that is responsible for the current `stroke-width` of your lines.
Then insert a rule, that is slightly more specific and change the value for `stroke-width` there.

In [this example from the nvd3 examples](http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html), the `stroke-width` is set by a rule like this:

```
.nvd3 .nv-groups path.nv-line
```

So we create a matching rule, which is slightly more specific, e.g.:

```
.nvd3 g.nv-groups path.nv-line
```

and attach a new value for `stroke-width` with it:

```
.nvd3 g.nv-groups path.nv-line {
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

Comment: But... how did you find that ? I can't see any stroke-width class in the code, or in the documentation...

Comment: @psv Using the developer tools of the browser, search through the HTML for the path elements and then use the style inspector.

Comment: Okay, and how do you know that we just have to add "g" to the class when we want to override it ? I still not understand that...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity and http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity  A rule of thumb is: Make the rule more specific, so that it targets less elements.

Comment: Very useful. Following the same, I discovered:   ``.nvd3 g.nv-groups .nv-point {
    stroke-opacity: 1!important;
    stroke-width: 2px!important;
    fill-opacity: 1!important;
  }``

Comment: @PatrickT You should not need the `!important`, when the selector is more specific as described.

Comment: Thanks Sirko, I added that to make sure it would overrule, but if you say it's not needed you must be right!

Comment: Finally! This is the answer I have been hunting for. 

Comment: @Sirko I see the css class containing the plots in the page inspector, but I can't find anything of the sort of `.nvd3 .nv-groups path.nv-line` on any CSS file in my site. I have an angular controller with the options for the plots, is there any way I can modify the width there?

Comment: @alonsos As said in the answer: search for the rule, that currently sets the value you want to change. The rule may be different for you, but there should be one. Then make a rule that is slightly more specific and override the value.

Comment: @Sirko I'm kind of new to this. Search for what rule? and where? How do I call it?